# Update a value in treeListView in objectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview, treelistview

I have built a treeListView:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TreeListViewTest1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = delegate(object x) 
            { 
                return true; 
            };
            this.treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object x) 
            {
                Contract contract = x as Contract;
                return contrat.Children;
            };

            column1.AspectGetter = delegate(object x)
            {
                if(x is Contract)
                {
                    return ((Contract)x).Name;
                }
                else
                {
                    return " ";
                }
            };

            column2.AspectGetter = delegate(object x)
            {
                if(x is Contract)
                {
                    return ((Contract)x).Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    Double d = (Double)x;
                    return d.ToString();
                }
            };

            this.treeListView1.AddObject(new Contract("A", 1));

        }

        private void treeListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Contract
    {
        public string Name { get; set;}
        public Double Value { get; set; }
        public List<Double> Children {get; set;}

        public Contract(string name, Double value)
        {
            Name = name;
            Value = value;
            Children = new List<Double>();
            Children.Add(2);
            Children.Add(3);
        }
    }
}
```

It gives this output:

```
Name     Value

A        1

         2

         3
```

How do I update the values of column2 ("Value") of the parent and the children from within an event? (increasing each value by of the parent and the children.)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

I do not understand if I have to use the AspectGetter again or can i modify just the values in column2 somehow and then refreshObjects().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I do not understand if I have to use the AspectGetter again or can i modify just the values in column2 somehow and then refreshObjects().

No, you should just manipulate the underlying model object and call `treeListView1.RefreshObject(myObject);` for example, where `myObject` should be a `Contract` in you case. This will refresh the contents of the respective rows.

I don't know what your button1_Click() is supposed to do, but you obviously require a reference of the object you want to refresh. This could be the currently selected object for example (`treeListView.SelectedObject`). If you tell what you want to do, I may be able to give you more information.

Comment: Ok thanks I have solved the refresh the values problem using refreshObjects() and changing the underlying model.

Comment: @azuric: Great. Since this answer helped to solve you problem you may accept it. Thanks.

Comment: What I would also like to know is how to click on a cell to fire an event? I do not want to edit the cell just fire an event that gives me the location of the cell eg column and row so that i can then do something

Comment: The `CellClick` event gives you plenty of information about the involved cell, the row and the associated model object. But if you just want to see that the user selected a new row, you would normally use `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectionChanged` events, and in the event handler check the `SelectedObject` property to get the model object of that row (or NULL if nothing was selected). Post a new question if you still have trouble, since it doesn't contribute to this one any longer.